# Sanitizing input to be used in pandas query with the str.contains method

Tags: python, pandas, input, sanitization

How can I sanitize the input in the code below so that it can be used to query a dataset `df`?

```py
query = f"`{field_name}`.str.contains('''{input()}''', case=False)"
df.query(query)
```

The main problem with the code above is that when the input contains triple quotes or backslashes it throws an error. Also keep in mind that the dataframe also contains backslashes in some cells and thus I would like the query to be able to perform that search as well (eg if the input is `a\s` I would like the query to return rows that contain `a\s` like for example `aaaa\saaaaa` would be a match).

Assume that `field_name` is given and not going to cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


s1 = pd.Series(['Mouse', 'dog  a\s', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN, 'aaaa\saaaaa', ' \  """   '])
s2 = s1.str.contains(input('input: '), regex=False)
print(s2)
```

```
input: a\s
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4      NaN
5     True
6    False
dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0

input: """
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4      NaN
5    False
6     True
dtype: object

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I am afraid that is not what I want. I need that same code to work inside a `pandas.DataFrame.query` function. Your code is functional as it is, but when I put it in a `query` function, like so: `df.query(f"`{field_name}`.str.contains('''{input()}''', case=False)")`, it doesn't work and throws errors. Essentially I am asking if there's a way to have the `str.contains` method work inside a `query` without problems.